# UITableView: How to know when all the cells of TableView with dynamic cell heights are resized?

Tags: ios, uitableview

The problem I am facing is that when I send a data to UITableView then I send a command to scroll the table to bottom. If cell heights are constant then my scrollToLastCell takes to last cell but with dynamic cell heights it doesn't always takes to last cell.

I want to know is there any way when I can be sure that all cells of my tableView is finished resizing and then I trigger scroll to bottom?

Comment: To the best of my understanding cell heights are calculated dynamically as and when they are reused.  So what i suspect the tableView is scroll the estimated height of the tableView. I hope someone more knowledgeable clarifies.

Comment: To the best of my understanding cell heights are calculated dynamically as and when they are reused.  So what i suspect the tableView is scroll the estimated height of the tableView. I hope someone more knowledgeable clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

In the Docs Apple states

> Important
>
> If your table view includes self-sizing cells, headers, or footers,
>   you must provide estimated heights for those items.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/estimating_the_height_of_a_table_s_scrolling_area

Given that, I'd suggest you to go ahead and use tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:) method

Comment: I am already doing estimated Row height. Problem is how to know that tableView has calculated all cell heights and then I can command to scroll to bottom

Comment: Sorry didn't understand it was about timing. You could add an observer to contentSize prop. of tableView and send the scroll command once it reaches your estimated tableview height. but it's not a thing that I've tried (to put an observer on contentSize), not seems so elegant and it might cause performance issues. Hope someone informs. good luck.